# Как с помощью Денвера запускать php страницы?

Tags: apache, php, mysql

Как с помощью Денвера запускать php страницы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В каталоге "home" Денвера создаете каталог с именем, которое вы выбрали для локального виртуального хоста, напр. "vasyapupkin.net".

В созданном каталоге создаете еще один, с именем "www". Какталог www будет корневой директорией вашего виртуального хоста. Перезагружаете Денвер, при загрузке он автоматически создаст виртуальный хост. После этого локально станет доступен домен "vasyapupkin.net". Введя это имя в качестве URL-а в браузере вы увидите начальную страницу своего локального сайта.

Небольшое дополнение.
Согласно дефолтным установкам апача в Денвере, файл index.php в любой директории автоматически выполняется при запросе данной директории, без указания конкретного файла. Например, для URL "http://vasyapupkin.net/"  по умолчанию выполнится файл "homevasyapupkin.netwwwindex.php". Или может отобразится файл index.html из той же директории, при отсутствии php-файла.

Answer (score 0):

Создаете php-страничку, кладете в каталог с сайтами denwer'а, заходите браузером на соответствующий адрес. Можно ориентировать на те примеры, которые уже есть в составе denwer'а.